# Clear System.Runtime.ObjectCache of one application from other application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, caching, load-balancing, objectcache

I have one `ASP.NET MVC` application (x.com) which uses `System.Runtime.ObjectCache`.

I want to clear the cache of x.com from another application y.com which is hosted on another server.

x.com is hosted in a load balanced environment. The cache should be cleared from all the servers in load balanced environment.

Can anyone suggest how to implement this?